# How to list directories in a GCS bucket using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I If you are using NodeJS GCS client library and want to list directories in your bucket, how do you do that?

Answer (score 9):

First add the dependency for the NodeJS GCS client library into your `package.json` file by running:

```
npm -i @google-cloud/storage --save
```

Then add this into your code to list **all files**:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
...
const projectId = '<<<<<your-project-id-here>>>>>';
const gcs = storage({
    projectId: projectId
});

let bucketName = '<<<<<your-bucket-name-here>>>>>';
let bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
bucket.getFiles({}, (err, files,apires) => {console.log(err,files,apires)});
```

This will return **all files** with full path into `files`.

To list only directories you must workaround a quirk in the client library that requires you to use no auto pagination and then returns an extra argument to the CB. To do so change the code to this:

```
let cb=(err, files,next,apires) => {
    console.log(err,files,apires);
    if(!!next)
    {
        bucket.getFiles(next,cb);
    }
}
bucket.getFiles({delimiter:'/', autoPaginate:false}, cb);
```

This will return a list of directories under the root path with trailing `/` in `apires.prefixes`.

To list only directories under `foo/` directory use this code:

```
let cb=(err, files,next,apires) => {
    console.log(err,files,apires);
    if(!!next)
    {
        bucket.getFiles(next,cb);
    }
}
bucket.getFiles({prefix:'foo/', delimiter:'/', autoPaginate:false}, cb);
```

Comment: The syntax has changed. You should now use `const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');` and `const gcs = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId
});`. Here is an example from the docs: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles

Comment: A question: shouldn't the options '{prefix:'foo/', delimiter:'/', autoPaginate:false}' also be used on the inner getFiles ?