# List Folders in Google Cloud Storage Bucket using Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've been looking for a way to retrieve only directories inside a bucket but not what's in them.

As per [Google Cloud Storage Docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#getFiles) one can filter by prefix by:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');  

const storage = new Storage();

const options = {
  prefix: prefix,
  delimiter: '/'
};
    
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .getFiles(options)
  .then(results => {
    const files = results[0];

    console.log('Files:');
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file.name);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

I've tried with several combinations using prefix: `""`, or prefix: `"*"`or prefix: `"\"`and so on but I can't get to make it return only the folders.

Has anybody been able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, `getFiles` method is not reading folders in the way you are using it. I have adapted the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829299/how-to-list-directories-in-a-gcs-bucket-using-nodejs) to print my buckets:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const projectId = 'PROJECT_ID';
const gcs = storage({
    projectId: projectId
});

let bucketName = 'BUCKET_NAME';
let bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
// bucket.getFiles({}, (err, files,apires) => {console.log(err,files,apires)});


let cb=(err, files,next,apires) => {
    /*console.log('Err:');
    console.log('Files:');
    console.log(files);*/
    console.log('Apires:');
    console.log(typeof apires);
    console.log(apires);
    console.log(apires.prefixes);
    if(!!next)
    {   
        bucket.getFiles(next,cb);
    }   
}

bucket.getFiles({delimiter:'/', autoPaginate:false}, cb);

/* 
// List folders inside folders
let cb=(err, files,next,apires) => {
    console.log(err,files,apires);
    if(!!next)
    {
        bucket.getFiles(next,cb);
    }
}
bucket.getFiles({prefix:'foo/', delimiter:'/', autoPaginate:false}, cb);
*/
```

And, even if this is not useful in this case, I suggest you to use [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) to determine specific formats for names.