# Google Cloud Function - Why bucket always returns empty array of files?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to reach files stored on my Firebase Storage to return a list of them to my APK. I made a cloud function, which is not working, even though when everything seems to be right settle.

**index.js**

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const images = require('./images.js');

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: '<my_id>',
    keyFilename: './key.json',
});

const bucket = storage.bucket('<my_bucket>')

exports.getImages = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    images.getImages(bucket).then(urls => response.send(urls))
})
```

**images.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getImages
}

const query = {
    directory: '/images'
};

async function getImages(bucket) {
    return bucket.getFiles(query).then(files => {
        console.log(files)
        getUrls(files).then(urls => console.log(urls))
            .catch(() => console.error('URLs failure'));
    }).catch(() => console.error('Files failure'));
}

function getUrls(files) {
    const promises = []
    files.forEach(file => promises.push(file.getDownloadURL()))
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

My `Key.json` is located inside my functions folder

**Key.json**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "…”,
  "private_key_id": “…”,
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY——…”,
  "client_email": “…”,
  "client_id": “…”,
  "auth_uri": “…”,
  "token_uri": “…”,
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": “…”,
  "client_x509_cert_url": “…”
}
```

**Storage Rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

Executing `getImages()` function output is:

```
console.log(files): [ [] ]
console.error('Files failure'): Files failure
```

What am I doing wrong here, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and main problem I had was connecting with my Google Cloud Service, this means:

1. I generated a brand new private key from Firebase Admin

[image: Firebase project]
[image: Project settings]
[image: Generate new key]

2. Downloaded file and settle on my project as my new `Key.json`
3. Then comes the trickiest part. According to [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start)'s documentation

> You can use the bucket references returned by the Admin SDK in conjunction with the official Google Cloud Storage client libraries to upload, download, and modify content in the buckets associated with your Firebase projects. Note that you do not have to authenticate Google Cloud Storage libraries when using the Firebase Admin SDK. The bucket references returned by the Admin SDK are already authenticated with the credentials used to initialize your Firebase app.

This means, if you are running you service locally (`npm run shell`), you need to instantiate your `firebase-admin`.

```
var serviceAccount = require("./key.json");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<my_project>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

and then calling

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('<my_bucket>.appspot.com')
```

you will be ready to access your files. When accessing your google functions directly through deployment or from [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com), then accessing your storage wouldn't require an `admin` initialization or the key itself such as the first exposed `index.js` on the question, turning the code only into something like

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
...
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: '<my_id>',
});

const bucket = storage.bucket('<my_bucket>')
...
```

Regarding what `Mayeru` said:

> you have specified the directory as "/images" but instead it should be "images/"

`"images/"`could be used for querying `prefix` parameters, not `directory`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829299/how-to-list-directories-in-a-gcs-bucket-using-nodejs) example shows how it works, like [its reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) to google's documentation as well.

The following code, with some promise tweaks and parsing JSON data for Android, works like a charm. Locally and remotely.

**index.js**

```
var serviceAccount = require("./key.json");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const images = require('./images.js');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://<my_project>.firebaseio.com"
});

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('<my_bucket>.appspot.com')

exports.getImages = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    images.getImages(bucket)
        .then(urls => response.status(200).send({ data: { urls } }))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
})
```

**images.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getImages
}

const query = {
    directory: 'images'
};

function getImages(bucket) {
    return bucket.getFiles(query)
        .then(response => getUrls(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

function getUrls(response) {
    const promises = []
    response.forEach( files => {
        files.forEach (file => {
            promises.push(getSignedUrl(file));
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(result => getParsedUrls(result));
}

function getSignedUrl(file) {
    return file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '09-01-2019'
    })
}

function getParsedUrls(result) {
    return JSON.stringify(result.map(mediaLink => createMedia(mediaLink)));
}

function createMedia(mediaLink) {
    const reference = {};
    reference.mediaLink = mediaLink[0];
    return reference;
}
```

This will for sure list all the files under `images` folder from your bucket and access their signed download urls to be rendered with libraries like `Fresco`. Last, but not least, the download URL will be exposed, but to make a `GET` request directly on it will require adjustment on your bucket permissions. Anyway, this "permissions thing" is another topic which you might find how to do it also here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The logs show:

```
[[]] // this is the "files" you retrieved.
Files failure
```

As you can see, you are not retrieving any file, hence why it fails the call to get URLs from empty array.

you have specified the directory as **"/images"** but instead it should be **"images/"**

That should be able to retrieved the proper folder.

Also, the function "getDownloadURL()" don't appear as supported for "file" objects on [nodejs lib documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html). You might be looking for [getSignedUrl](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) ?

Comment: Hi Mayeru, thanks for supporting me ; I found the answer and it was mostly related to Private Key and how I was calling the Firebase Service ; I will be posting my answer ASAP =)

Comment: No problem, glad you have found the proper solution!